# Using the loop value inside an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want loop through 1 to 21 and then use this loop numbers for getting an Array of Strings ['e1.wkh',...'e21.wkh']. But right now the only value I got is ['e21.wkh'].

```
function calculateStats() {

    var obj = {}

    var deviceId = "34534";

    for (var i = 1; i <= 21; i++) {

        var loo = i.toString();

        console.log(loo);

        obj[deviceId] = ['e' + loo + '.kwh'];

        console.log(obj[deviceId]);
    }

}
```

Comment: The reason is that you are always using `deviceId` as the element name here: `obj[deviceId] = ['e' + loo + '.kwh'];` So you always overwrite the last value of `obj[deviceId]` How should the elements be named instead?

Comment: index of your obj remain's same for for whole loop that is your problem        in statement obj[deviceId] = ['e' + loo + '.kwh']; you have to Change this and make index incremental to store all the values generated by your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below line

```
obj[deviceId] = ['e' + loo + '.kwh'];
```

With

```
(obj[deviceId])?obj[deviceId].push('e' + loo + '.kwh'):obj[deviceId]=['e' + loo + '.kwh'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

The issue was you were overwriting your obj[deviceId].

```
function calculateStats() {

    var obj = {}

    var deviceId = "357803045265259@rayleigh";

    obj[deviceId] = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 21; i++) {

        var loo = i.toString();

        console.log(loo);

        obj[deviceId].push('e' + loo + '.kwh');

        console.log(obj[deviceId]);
    }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q651uhde/

Comment: obj[deviceId] should be equal to the array of 'e' + loo + '.kwh'

Comment: I have updated with a jsfiddle. It is an array of 'e' + loo + '.kwh'.

Comment: I have got such an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Did you add this line before the for loop: obj[deviceId] = []; ?

Comment: Alright it is working and both the ternary operation : (obj[deviceId])?obj[deviceId].push('e' + loo + '.kwh'):obj[deviceId]=['e' + loo + '.kwh'];

Answer (score 0):

function calculateStats() {

var obj = [];

```
var deviceId = "1111@rayleigh";

for (var i = 1; i <= 21; i++) {

    var loo = i.toString();

    console.log(loo);

    obj.push('e' + loo + '.kwh');


}
```

console.log(obj);

}
obj carries your array, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Set up the array first and then push each string to it. No need to convert the index to a string as it will be coerced to a string when you push it to the array anyway.

```
function calculateStats() {

  var obj = {};
  var deviceId = "357803045265259@rayleigh";
  obj[deviceId] = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= 21; i++) {
    obj[deviceId].push('e' + i + '.kwh');
  }

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/curx5xvd/)